# Javadoc: link to package-info

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm using package-info.java files in my javadoc. I'm trying to link from classes contained in a package to the package-info of the very same package. I have tried several options inspired by [this Oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see).

For example, the package is:

> com.zombo.apps.api.stream

I'm inside com.orcsoftware.apps.api.stream.someClass and am writing

> @see com.zombo.apps.api.stream.package-info

The link doesn't get rendered in the javadoc. How can I link to the package-info?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you remove the `.package-info` it should work nicely:

```
@see com.zombo.apps.api.stream
```

Comment: thanks. I did that before but it didn't work. Your comment made me try again. I played around with the javadoc compilation settings. I had to set the package flag as well. That made it work. I would have almost given up without your comment! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For those who want to reference a package-info without using the `@see` tag:
`{@link com.zombo.apps.api.stream}` also works.

Answer (score 0):

In a module application (when you have a `module-info.java` file in the source path) the package link should start with a module name reference. For example:

`@see module/package.class#member`

See chapter "References" in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html